# Cannot change JENKINS_HOME path on mac?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Using jenkins v2.401.2 locally on my **macbook pro m2 max**

Tried `export JENKINS_HOME=/Users/whoami/Desktop/jenkins` (the path is correct)

Restarted jenkins via brew: `brew services restart jenkins-lts`

Jenkins still shows the default path it got assigned after installation.

How do I solve this trivial issue?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Couse may be in **jenkins service user** env vars. Use `ps aux| grep -i jenkins` to discover it.
Also export is not permament. And exists only in current session in current shell. There is some crazy dances with bashrc & zshrc on mac which must be execute for every user

P.S. best practice for jenkins on macos is jenkins in docker =)

Answer (score -1):

Brew uses launchctl in mac.
To set env variable you can edit /etc/launchd.conf (create if not present)
or you can run `launchctl setenv JENKINS_HOME /Users/whoami/workSpace`

and then run `brew services restart jenkins-lts`.

I have tested this with my mac.

Comment: Please read my question before answering.

Comment: Apologies that i missed, I have updated my comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).